# Apply UK VIsa without passport details

Tags: visas, uk

I have applied for my passport but it will take some time. Can I still apply for UK visa without passport details?
I will produce my passport at the time of verification.

Comment: Most likely not. Is it possible for you to expedite the passport issuance process by paying more for a expedited service?

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

In order to apply, you must input the details of the passport you’ll be using to travel when you complete the online application.

Source: [Documents and information you’ll need to apply](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/apply-standard-visitor-visa)

However, once you’ve started your application you can save your form and complete it later when you receive your passport.

Comment: I expect that saving the form and completing it later means that the form has not been submitted, and therefore processing has not started? It would be good to specify it -- since pre-completing as many details as possible then does not earn much -- as well as how much time the data is retained (if it expires).